# in nvd3 multibarchart, some stacks lose their colors or otherwise become invisible

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How do I ensure that bars in multibarchart in nvd3 always starts from same level? What I am seeing is that some series start kinda "floating" in the air (actually one of the stacks loses its color)

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2kH/1/ and click on "stacked" option (initial settings - that is another question)

My data series is very short, just 3 rows - 2 in one sub-series and 1 in another sub-series.

```
data_multiBarChart = [{
    'values': [ {
        'y': 7,
            'x': 9
    }],
        'key': 'Count',
        'yAxis': '1'
}, {
    'values': [{
        'y': 12,
            'x': 0
    }, {
        'y': 8,
            'x': 1
    }],
        'key': 'Duration',
        'yAxis': '1'
}];
```

Thanks.

--EDIT--

FWIW warnings seen in firebug console:

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute.
this.setAttribute(name, f(t));
```

I have also seen with similarly sparse data:

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute.
...3.interpolateRgb=function(e,t){e=d3.rgb(e),t=d3.rgb(t);var n=e.r,r=e.g,i=e.b,s=t...
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the data you are passing into the chart. The count of sub-series in you chart must be equal, if you do not have a value you must at least set the y value to 0.

A multiple bar graph contains comparisons of two or more categories or bars. When the chart is drawn, the **`X-Axis`** must be in a sequence, take a look at how the **`X-Axis`** is lined up in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/hjWAs/)

Try using the data as shown below :

```
data_multiBarChart = [{
    'values': [{
        'y': 0,
            'x': 1
    }, {
        'y': 8,
            'x': 2
    }],
        'key': 'Count',
        'yAxis': '1'
}, {
    'values': [{
        'y': 12,
            'x': 1
    }, {
        'y': 8,
            'x': 2
    }],
        'key': 'Duration',
        'yAxis': '1'
}];
```

Hope I made sense, and helps solve your problem.

Comment: It explains (+1) but does not solve the problem. Why should a "0" be coerced in where a "null" existed before? For example it might interfere with onclick/callback arguments. If the renderer needed to make the assumption then that's the place to do it.

Comment: The Multibar Chart requires an Integer for its X and Y axis, so a null will not work. If you are not looking for a comparison between the two  sub-series, you could try a NVD3 Discrete Chart. Hey at the end of the day NVD3 is just a set of reusable charts that was built for a general use,  if you are trying to go beyond what they provide, you might have to tinker with the source, or create your own.