# NVD3 MultiBarChart Stacked Display with Non-Normalized Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have multiple datasets that I am passing to an NVD3 multiBarChart. The problem is, the chart doesn't seem to display correctly **in stacked mode** if some properties are missing from one set vs the other.

Let's say I have a list of User's weekly drink preferences:

```
[
    {
        userName: "Todd",
        values: [
            { 
                x: "Coffee",
                y: 32
            },
            {
                x: "Tea",
                y: 13
            },
            {
                x: "Beer",
                y: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        userName: "Allison",
        values: [
            { 
                x: "Coffee",
                y: 4
            },
            {
                x: "Milk",
                y: 2
            },
            {
                x: "Sprite",
                y: 14
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        userName: "Vern",
        values: [
            { 
                x: "Water",
                y: 112
            },
            {
                x: "Gatorade",
                y: 13
            },
            {
                x: "Beer",
                y: 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Since not all "users" have the same drinks, the graph won't display correctly **in stack mode**.

If I normalize the data so that each user will have ALL the same drinks, with the previously missing values getting a `0` value, the stacked mode will display correctly.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically normalize the data so that all "users" arrays will have the same object count.

This is similar to the post here: [in nvd3 multibarchart, some stacks lose their colors or otherwise become invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938056/in-nvd3-multibarchart-some-stacks-lose-their-colors-or-otherwise-become-invisib), however, I am looking for a way to programmatically normalize the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most efficient way to do it, but doesn't use any libraries and should work fine for not too large amounts of data:

```
var drinks = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.values.forEach(function(e) {
    if(drinks.indexOf(e.x) == -1) drinks.push(e.x);;
  });
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  drinks.forEach(function(drink) {
    var have = false;
    d.values.forEach(function(e) {
        if(e.x == drink) have = true;
    });
    if(!have) d.values.push({x: drink, y: 0});
  });
});
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7pC6X/).